# How to know what version of Adobe Acrobat is in my browser?

Tags: javascript, adobe, version, acrobat

I have already the code for Adobe detection but, I need to know which version of Adobe Acrobat I have in my browser.

```
    <script>
    var p; // variable local para detectar el acrobat 
    var compatibleadobeacrobat=false; // variable booleana del detector acrobat
    try { 
    p = new ActiveXObject('AcroExch.Document'); 
    } 
    catch (e) { 


    // active x object could not be created 
    document.write('<img src="imagenes/iconos_VX_s2.png" width="26" height="20">');
    compatibleadobeacrobat=false; 
    document.write("<br>compatible: "+compatibleadobeacrobat);
    } 
    if (p){ 
    document.write('<img src="imagenes/iconos_VX_s1.png" width="26" height="20">'); 
    compatibleadobeacrobat=true;
    document.write("<br>compatible: "+compatibleadobeacrobat);
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `navigator`'s property `plugins` to get plugins array and after finding Adobe Reader, recieve version from it's `version` property?

I don't know how Adobe Reader add-on is called, so this code is untested but it should work.

```
var pl = navigator.plugins;

if(pl)
{
  var where = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<pl.length;i++)
  {
    var name = pl[i].name;
    if(name.search('Adobe PDF Reader')!=-1)
    {
      where = i;
    }
    if(where)
      break;
  } 
  var ver = pl[where].version;
}
```

Comment: thanks Kuba in the if i write 
if(name.search('Adobe Acrobat')!=-1)

and its works